# Replace dynamic value between dynamic characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string between characters like this:

```
new/set/25/
type/22/set/3/
aa/23/mine/set/9/yous
set/34
/dol/22/mmm/sss/set/23
```

it has a  value pattern like this:

```
set/{n}
```

i tried to replace the `{n}` value using this function:

```
var pathname = 'new/set/9/'   
pathName = pathName.replace(/(/\//gset/\//g)([0-9]+)/, '$1' + '5';
//expected result = new/set/5/
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.match` method to replace all capturing parentheses value by any other result like bellow

```js
let pattern = /set\/(\d+)\/?/;

let chaines = [
  "new/set/25/",
  "type/22/set/3/",
  "aa/23/mine/set/9/yous",
  "set/34",
  "dol/22/mmm/sss/set/23"
];

chaines.map(c => {
  let matches = c.match(pattern);
  console.log(c.replace(matches[1], 5));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```js
let pathname = `uid/22/new/set/203/key/90`;
pathname = pathname.replace(/(?<=set\/)\d+(?=\/)/g, 5);

console.log(pathname);
```

Comment: how to do it using the replace function , because im plannging to put this 'new/set/{n}' string in the url

Comment: @Padawan thanks for your reference, however when i have a string like this: `uid/22/new/set/203/key/90` it will become `uid/5/new/set/5/key/90`  instead of `uid/22/new/set/5/key/90`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex paterrn  `(?<=set\/)\d+(?=\/)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbWsCD/8)**

```js
console.log('uid/22/new/set/203/key/90'.replace(/(?<=set\/)\d+(?=\/)/g,'78'))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what if the string inside the dynamic url for example if i have string like this `uid/22/new/set/203/key/90`